# case_when where replaced columns have different types

Tags: r

I am working on the following problem which requires to use case_when. However, I encounter the error message `Error: must be a logical vector, not a double vector` because the replaced columns are not the same type (some logical and some double due to `bind_rows`). I am looking for a clean solution to get the desired output.

```
#set empty dataframe with column names
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 0)), c("a", "b", "c","d","e")) 
df_subset <- data.frame(b=c(1,2))
df1 <- bind_rows(df,df_subset)%>%mutate(type="b")
df1
   a b  c  d  e type
1 NA 1 NA NA NA    b
2 NA 2 NA NA NA    b

df1%>%mutate(result=case_when(type=="a"~a,
                              type=="b"~b,
                              type=="c"~c,
                              type=="d"~d,
                              type=="e"~e,
                              T~NA_real_))

Error: must be a logical vector, not a double vector
```

Expected output: **(Note: I do not always know if column b has values)**

```
df1%>%mutate(a=NA_real_,
             c=NA_real_,
             d=NA_real_,
             e=NA_real_,
             result=case_when(type=="a"~a,
                              type=="b"~b,
                              type=="c"~c,
                              type=="d"~d,
                              type=="e"~e,
                              T~NA_real_))

#desired output
   a b  c  d  e type result
1 NA 1 NA NA NA    b      1
2 NA 2 NA NA NA    b      2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine if you fix all types to numeric.

#### `dplyr` Solution

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(a:e, as.numeric)) %>%  # this is the fix
  mutate(result=case_when(type=="a"~a,
                          type=="b"~b,
                          type=="c"~c,
                          type=="d"~d,
                          type=="e"~e,
                          T~NA_real_))
```

### Output

```
#>    a b  c  d  e type result
#> 1 NA 1 NA NA NA    b      1
#> 2 NA 2 NA NA NA    b      2
```

Comment: Thank you! For those working on ```dplyr``` < 1.0.0, use ```mutate_at(vars(a:e),as.numeric)``` instead of ```mutate(across(a:e, as.numeric))```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you might be looking for:

```
df1 %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(result = get(type))

  a         b c     d     e     type  result
  <lgl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 NA        1 NA    NA    NA    b          1
2 NA        2 NA    NA    NA    b          2
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the way you created the `matrix` results in a logical matrix. Then `b` column was created as an integer column.

Inspect this with `str(df1)`.

Then `case_when()` sees the mixed types. `a` being logical, and `b` being integer. As seen in the error message.

See the documentation in the details section of `?matrix` for more.

The solution is to make an integer matrix at the beginning. Then your original code works.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA_integer_, nrow=2, ncol=5, dimnames=list(1:2, letters[1:5])))
df$b <- c(1,2)
df$type <- c("b","b")
df %>% mutate(result=case_when(type=="a"~a,
                               type=="b"~b,
                               type=="c"~c,
                               type=="d"~d,
                               type=="e"~e,
                               T~NA_integer_))
                          
#   a b  c  d  e type result
#1 NA 1 NA NA NA    b      1
#2 NA 2 NA NA NA    b      2
```

Answer (score 3):

This one could also be an option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% 
  mutate(result=case_when(type=="a"~a,
                          type=="b"~b,
                          type=="c"~c,
                          type=="d"~d,
                          type=="e"~e,
                          TRUE~NA_character_)) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

```
  a         b c     d     e     type  result
  <lgl> <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>  <int>
1 NA        1 NA    NA    NA    b          1
2 NA        2 NA    NA    NA    b          2
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(result = cur_data()[[type]]) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  a         b c     d     e     type  result
  <lgl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 NA        1 NA    NA    NA    b          1
2 NA        2 NA    NA    NA    b          2
```